# What is the state of the art in procedural character animations?

Tags: procedural-generation, skeletal-animation

I'm a programmer and I'm interested in programmatic character animation — walking or running, bipedal or many-legged: what is the state of the art today?

I heard about NaturalMotion's [Euphoria](http://www.naturalmotion.com/middleware/euphoria/) system and Ubisoft's [IK Rig](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F0FVCrSXA1U), and they look amazing. Where can I find more info about similar algorithms?

Comment: I really don't think anyone does anything quite like NaturalMotion's physics-based animation system. You'll find that's the sort of thing that encapsulates years of rigourous work by a dedicated, specialised team. It is a highly specialised product. Best of breed, as they say. Hence the pricetag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IK Rig looks very cool, and from what I can find, it's all in the name. It's about using Inverse Kinematics, prescribing the bare minimum number of elements for describing an animation -- feet, pelvis, wrists, shoulders, neck-base and head. Everything in between is constrained according to artistic factors and calculated in-engine, or baked to a new, more fully-defined animation.

Based on slides downloaded from the description of one of their videos ([see description](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hRdksD5X8SM), but be warned: 1.2 GB and not much information):

> **IK Rig Definition**
>
> ● Active bones – full body IK
>
> ● Twist bones, small bones, secondary bones, collider, pivot, prop
>   nodes – added and constrained directly in engine

This is accompanied by a picture of their IK rig's active bones -- feet, pelvis, wrists, shoulders, neck-base and head.

[Another of their videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4DyO_VS_3Gk) contains a more informative set of slides in its description (0.8 GB). It describes 3 steps:

1. Convert Source -- Mocap or other animation is converted into "IK
   chain proxy format".
2. Adjust -- Behaviours are changed/constrained
   according to the desires of the artist applying these animations to
   the character.
3. Apply to target -- These are then animated at runtime
   or saved as a more traditional animation.

With all this info, if I were you, I'd learn about Inverse Kinematics -- I've never done it before, but I'd probably Google "Inverse Kinematics" for more information on that specifically.

Comment: Thanks. Last couple of days I'm researching IK Rig system. I looked the slides, watched GDC and nucl.ai talks and I have the similar understanding to yours. Thought without a code it's not absolutely clear. Specifically, how to convert. adjust and apply.

Comment: Yeah, code can really help. Sometimes you've just gotta try it and see, though :)

Comment: If you want code example they reference FINAL IK which is an asset from the asset store that almost do similar things, and teh code is viewable.